Question when obtaining magnetic flux density B
I am trying to obtain the magnetic flux density B of a toroidal transformer with one winding around the core. I am injecting a voltage in the terminals of the winding, and I am measuring this voltage and the current flowing trough the winding.
I want to obtain the exciting current- flux density curve, so in the x-axis I am plotting the current and the flux density in the y-axis.

My problem is that I am not obtaining the right amplitude of the saturation density according to the material, even if the shape of the curve seems correct.
For example, the max amplitude I am obtaining is around 1.5T, when according to the material of my transformer, the amplitude should be around 1.9 T. The equation I am using to obtain B is the next:
B=(1/Winding turns*Core Cross section area)*Integral(Vs).
With the equation to obtain the max. value of flux density of a toroidal core, the max. values are around 1.9 T, but the shape is not the expected.
The eq. used to obtain this is: B=Voltage/(4.44*frequency*Turns*Core Cross section area).
T
This is the shape of the voltage for reference, the max value is 9.6 V and the min is -9.8V.
So why I am not obtaining the right amplitude of B with the first equation, even if the shape is correct?

What voltage waveform are you injecting? Urms=4.44fNAB is only true for sinusoidal waveform without DC.

It would be helpful if you share your measurements.

Hello, thanks for your comments. I am injecting a sinusoidal voltage. Also, I will add the results in the post.

First, your formula applies to sinewave input (yours appears to have some harmonics). Second, the Voltage in the formula is the RMS, not the peak (just wanted to point out in case you're using the peak).

Thanks for the comment, the input is a sine wave, the voltage seen is the one measured when the CT reaches saturation. And yes, I am aware the Voltage used in the second formula is the rms.

You say you are injecting a sinusoidal voltage, but you have a graph that shows voltage vs time and the this graphs is not sinusoidal. Is the graph actually of current, even though it is labeled voltage? Also, a schematic of your setup might be worth a 1000 words.
